# Set inner counter initial value as 0 in second time iteration in Jmeter

Tags: for-loop, jmeter, counter

I have Parent For loop & its counter element is added. In parent for loop, i have added another child for loop, & in child loop, another counter element is added.

So when Parent loop count is 1, Child loop counter starts from 0 to 4(Depends on Max num), But when parent loop count is 2, Child loop counter starts from 5 to so on, but i want to again execute it from 0 to N (Any number).

[Image shows counter value of parent & child loop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yccYz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to achieve it using [Counters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter), you will need to go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and the expression like:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller - Inner Loop__idx')) as int % 5,)}
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands.

Demo:

[image]